# How to allow powershell to run .net c# console .exe

Tags: c#, .net, console

I am looking into to this, and can't seem to find the answer. I need to be able to make my console application be put on a machine, so that a powershell script can call my console application with a param. I have it all coded out, but tried to take the .EXE from the debug folder, and caused errors. Does anyone know how to do this, as if it were like back in the days of making an VB6 .EXE and putting it anywhere?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the console application have references to dlls? Copy them over to the same directory.

Comment: Then what? Do they just call the .exe that is from the bin folder?

Comment: If you copy the console exe into a new folder, can you run it fine? If so the issue is with how you call it from PS.

Answer (score 0):

Example Console application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

I complle and then I go to the bin directory (or any directory I have moved the application AND any referenced libraries) within PowerShell and type:

```
myappname.exe "hello world"
```

And my app (through the PS window) spits that back out at me.

So check for any referenced files not existing in the same folder as your exe.